# Name binding in function statements

Tags: python, function, name-binding

The following Python program:

```py
d = {}

for x in range(3):
    d[x] = lambda: x

print(d[0](), d[1](), d[2]())
```

outputs:

```
2 2 2
```

`x` is bound by *reference* in the `lambda` expression. After the `for` statement, `x` is bound to 2, which explains the output.

I would like `x` to be bound by *value* instead, to get the following output:

```
0 1 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `d[x] = lambda y=x: y`

Comment: @alaniwi Thanks. I can also use `d[x] = (lambda y: (lambda: y))(x)`.